# Change menu button using XML configuration

Tags: android, xml, menu

If I create an  Options menu with menu.xml, can I change the menu buttons' standard text size, color etc? I would like to change text size, bold, and color.

I would like to avoid using themes and styles for this application.

Answer (score 2):

=( Sorry you can't change text size or color creatin a menu from an .xml file.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I had searched the attributes for a menu.xml and it didn't look good but I thought I would ask in case I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can, try this solution:
http://www.techjini.com/blog/2011/04/19/customizing-background-and-text-color-in-options-menu-android/